# Add object key to each item in object array

Tags: javascript

I have a payload coming back from an endpoint like this:

```
const charges = [
    {
        'id': 'someId',
        'dates': ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'],
    },
    {
        'id': 'anotherId',
        'dates': ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'],
    },
];
```

What would be the best way to attach `id` to each of the items in the `dates` array so that it results in this:

```
[
    { id: 'someId', date: '2017-11-11' },
    { id: 'someId', date: '2017-12-11' },
    { id: 'anotherId', date: '2017-09-11' },
    { id: 'anotherId', date: '2017-10-11' },
]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
let history = [];
charges.map(charge => (
    charge.dates.map((date) => (
        history.concat({
            id: charge.payerCode,
            date: date,
        })
    ))
));
```

But history is not defined in the scope I'm using it in.

I know there is probably a better way to do this, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: please tell me what output example you expect?

Comment: Added to the question to desired output. Sorry!

Comment: Are you trying to make `history` contain your desired output?

Comment: `map` isn't the right tool here as your output array won't possibly have the same number of elements than your input array. `reduce` is the tool to use, as proposed in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) while concat all objects, build with dates arrays.

```js
let charges = [{ id: 'someId', dates: ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'] }, { id: 'anotherId', dates: ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'] }],
    result = charges.reduce((r, { id, dates }) => r.concat(dates.map(date => ({ id, date }))), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Edge version, which prevents (it might be a bug inside of Edge)

> ```
> SCRIPT5113: Use before declaration
> result = charges.reduce((r, { id, dates }) => r.concat(dates.map(date => ({ id, date }))), []);
>                                                                             ^
> ```

```js
const
    charges = [{ id: 'someId', dates: ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'] }, { id: 'anotherId', dates: ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'] }],
    result = charges.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a.dates.map(d => ({ id: a.id, date: d }))), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const charges = [
    {
        'id': 'someId',
        'dates': ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'],
    },
    {
        'id': 'anotherId',
        'dates': ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'],
    },
];

function flatten(charges) {    
  return charges.reduce((p, {id, dates}) => 
           (dates.forEach(date => p.push({id, date})), p), []);    
}

console.log(flatten(charges))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in combination with [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like this :

```js
const charges = [
    {
        'id': 'someId',
        'dates': ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'],
    },
    {
        'id': 'anotherId',
        'dates': ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'],
    },
];

var r = charges.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  return acc.concat(obj.dates.map(function(date) {
    return {
      id : obj.id,
      date : date
    };
  }))
}, []);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple imperative solution would be:

```
const history = [];
for (const { payerCode, dates } of charges) {
  for (const date of dates) {
    history.push({ id: payerCode, date });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivq9WV18fVAhXHNY8KHQgZCTwQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) recreate the array and [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0uNPI18fVAhVKro8KHewUBpoQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg) to iterate the inner array

```js
const charges = [{'id': 'someId', 'dates': ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'],}, { 'id': 'anotherId','dates': ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'],},];

var res = charges.reduce(function(a,b){
b.dates.forEach(function(n){
a.push({id:b.id,dates:n})
})
return a;
},[])

console.log(res)
```

**ES6**

```js
const charges = [{'id': 'someId', 'dates': ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'],}, { 'id': 'anotherId','dates': ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'],},];

var res = charges.reduce((a,b) =>(b.dates.forEach(d=>a.push({id:b.id,dates:d})),a),[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const charges = [
    {
        'id': 'someId',
        'dates': ['2017-11-11', '2017-12-11'],
    },
    {
        'id': 'anotherId',
        'dates': ['2017-09-11', '2017-10-11'],
    },
];
var temp={};
var finalArray = [];
for(ch in charges){
    for(dt of charges[ch]['dates']){
        temp.id = charges[ch]['id'];
        temp.date =dt;
        finalArray.push(temp);
        temp={};
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
});
```